# What is the difference between allMatch and anyMatch behaviour for empty streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Can we except that they behave the same for any collection, even empty one?

Comment: This is clearly documented in the javadoc. Where does your confusion come from?

Comment: I read it when had this problem, someone might look in stackoverflow first. It says it's ok to place Q&A tips here.

Comment: It can be. We still have the same quality expectations for questions that are self answered. Your question currently doesn't fit those expectations. For example, show some research effort. What led you to believe there is a difference or that there isn't?

Comment: Yes, you might _look_ in StackOverflow first.  You might also just write the 10 lines of code it takes to try this out.  Knowing _how to learn_ and _how to find information on the Internet_ are very important skills in software development (well, in all of life actually) and you should endeavor to improve in those areas. That means not asking until you've exhausted other resources.

Comment: From an English dictionary; "all" - used to refer to the whole quantity or extent of a particular group or thing.  "any" - used to refer to one or some of a thing or number of things, no matter how much or how many.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can simply check that:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Any match returns " + list.stream().anyMatch(number -> number > 0));
        System.out.println("All match returns " + list.stream().allMatch(number -> number > 0));
    }
}
```

That outputs:

```
Any match returns false
All match returns true
```

So, **anyMatch** returns **false** for empty stream, but **allMatch** returns **true**. It doesn't matter what condition you have inside them in that case. That was not obvious to me. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: You have answered you own question but is the meaning or "all" or "any" in question? Are you answering a question no body would ask?